# jquery/rails exception for fading out flash message

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following code in `application.js` to fade out flash messages:

```
//fadeout flash messages
$('.flash').fadeIn(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.flash').fadeOut();
    }, '2000');
});
```

However, in `sessions_controller.rb`, if a login error occurs, a message is flashed which will include a link to reset the user's password - and I don't want this link to fade out!

```
flash.now[:login_error] = "Invalid email/password combination.  
                           Have you #{ActionController::Base.helpers.link_to "forgotten your password?", '#'}".html_safe
```

Is there a way to make `flash` messages of type `login_error` exempt from the code in `application.js`?

## edit:

html of the `login_error` message - actually it's just a css class, so it should be easy.

```
<div class="flash login_error">
  Invalid email/password combination.  
  Have you <a href="#">forgotten your password?</a>
</div>
```

## solution:

[techvineet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1460496/techvineet)'s suggestion to disable fadein if the user was not logged in is a good one - I did it like this which is quite broad but the easiest way I could think of - in `application.html.erb`:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" unless current_user.nil?  %>
```

However, [arjan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/887533/arjan)'s answer targets only what I want more explicitly.

Comment: Can you please post the HTML of the login error message, and a standard error message.

Comment: You can enable the fadein function only when the user is logged in

Comment: @dax - if it really helped please vote up for this comment.

Comment: make an answer and i will do - i don't think you get karma for comments :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery's `not` method http://api.jquery.com/not/.

```
//fadeout flash messages
$('.flash').not('.login_error').fadeIn(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.flash').fadeOut();
    }, '2000');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can enable the fadein function only when the user is logged in